# How to get value from datatable when the column is null value

Tags: vb.net, datatable, integer, nullable

I am rather new in VB2015. I got a problem when I try to get a value from datatable. The type of the column is integer while its value is null. My variable is cc. Part of my code belows. I got "specified cast is not valid". Pleas advise

```
      Dim cc As Nullable(Of Integer)
        cc = Nothing

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            cc = dt.Rows(0).ItemArray(0)
            If cc Is Nothing Then
                toID = 0
            Else
                toID = cc
            End If
            toName = dt.Rows(0).ItemArray(1).ToString
        Else
            toID = 0
            toName = ""
        End If
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: You could check against DBNull.Value instead of Nothing.

Comment: Thank I solve it. Using DBnull.value

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but too big for a comment.

You can simplify your code by using the Field(Of T) method of the DataRow combined with the If operator, note that you shouldn't need a nullable cc if you don't want to use the value - something like this:

```
Dim cc as Integer
cc = If(dt.Rows(0).Field(Of Integer?)(0), 0)

If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    toName = dt.Rows(0).Field(Of String)(1)
Else
    toID = 0
    toName = ""
End If
```